# Automate Password Set And Verify

Tags: password, encryption, automation

I'm using this to set passwords in a script:

```
usermod -p `mkpasswd -H md5 passwordText` user
```

I need to create an exception in my script, just in case this command fails.  What file contains the encrypted password and how do I reverse the encryption so I can verify it was written to the file correctly?

Edit: I finally found the problem with the line above.  The password was allowing symbols that were being interpreted as wildcards on the command line making it appear as if the command itself failed.  Nonetheless, it's lead me to new things I'm glad I know now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reversing the the shadow- file, why not just do:

```
usermod -p `mkpasswd -H md5 passwordText` user

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Changing password failed!!!!!!"
fi
```

You could replace whatever you want in the `if` block, but if a command ever fails for `usermod` it'll return a non-zero status.

Comment: I will give this a try because it sounds like it might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The password is stored in `/etc/shadow` and you can try to confirm it with john the ripper.

I am not sure if posting tutorials for john are allowed here, if so I can write one easily enough, but if not a google search will show you how.

Last I looked, John needed a patch, but the bug report on launchpad seemed to indicate that the patch was incorporated into the repos, so I would try the un-patched version first (I know, lazy =) ).

Short of john, `su - test_user` -> enter password.

Brief tutorial on john the ripper:

Install john

```
sudo apt-get install john
```

Prepare the working database (I made a user "test" with a weak password for this example).

```
sudo unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > password.db
```

Run john

```
john password.db

Loaded 2 password hashes with 2 different salts (generic crypt(3) [?/64])
Remaining 1 password hash
guesses: 0  time: 0:00:00:03 0% (2)  c/s: 222  trying: monday - emily
```

As you can see, john cracked the weak password in 0.03 seconds, my user password is too strong for john so I aborted it with <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Show the password

```
john --show password.db

test:testing:1001:1001:,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash

1 password hash cracked, 1 left
```

Here we see the user "test" with the password "testing"

```
su test
Password:
```

test@ufbt:/home/test

Comment: I actually not trying to crack the password, but I may be missing a description from my search on the ripper that it does simple reversals.  Either way, I'm glad you brought it up.  I think I could use the ripper in a script to test the passwords I'm making to improve security.  It's better I understand what the black hat may use.  Design based on secrets is the real threat, not an open platform that has to deal with the truth.

Comment: There is nothing quite like seeing john crack your password in less then 1 second to make you appreciate strong passwords.

Comment: I've decided against using john at startup to create a stronger password.  It would frustratingly increase boot time.